# i try to install ubuntu on my bootable USB but it stuck

Tags: system-installation, live-usb, filesystem

1. i am trying to install Ubuntu onto my bootable USB that make persistent data and did not alter my main OS.
2. i am running on a 32gb Sandisk drive. The ISO file and the device that i am trying to install are the same one.
3. i am already use rufus and ISO file onto my USB
4. in ubuntu system, i already umount the device
5. Right now i am try to install ubuntu on other device option
6. the problem is,

during installation, i did choose my USB drive and when i try to format it to "ext4 journaling file system" with mount point "/"

i am getting an error which is "the ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sdb) failed"

Comment: i am trying to edit and answer to your answer as best as i can, and your 2nd question, it seem like i did make a mistake there, can you explaint it on detail?

Comment: i am trying to use ver16 32bit. Since my notebook smaller device

Comment: Usually, you install the iso to one USB drive and then you can install Ubuntu onto *another* USB drive but not the same drive. Do you have another USB drive?

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu is already a live os you could create persistance to save the created data on live ubuntu. Rather than installing the entire ubuntu on same usb which contains all the ubuntu installation files.

Comment: i already did learning that said it will never be persistent when i am only use "try" option instead of install option in the beginning of startup. and i also did try to make it, and it work just like i am mention above

Comment: @random Can you please elaborate what you're trying to say and how this would answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to create a LiveUSB for Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit, and have a Windows machine available (the one you ran [Rufus](https://rufus.ie) on), we will follow the [Windows process](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14912/create-a-persistent-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive/) which is about 80% down the page after the lengthy Ubuntu process.

Step 1: [Install LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download) on Windows.
Step 2: Insert your flash drive you wish to use as the LiveUSB.
Step 3: Launch LiLi as an Admnistrator.
Step 4: Follow the steps at the [LiLi Help Guide](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/help/guide).